# More elegant way of guarantying a method can´t use negative numbers?

Tags: java, if-statement, negative-number

I have this exercise I have to do for my class. I can´t change how the method works and it is a pretty stupid method. I was wondering, though, if there is a more elegant way of guarantying this method can´t use negative numbers. I used a pretty big if:

```
void abreTeatro(int codigoCamarote,  int capacidadeCamarote, 
        int precoCamarote, int codigoFrente, int capacidadeFrente, 
        int precoFrente, int codigoMeio, int capacidadeMeio, 
        int precoMeio, int codigoFundo, int capacidadeFundo, 
        int precoFundo)
{
    if ((codigoCamarote > 0) && (capacidadeCamarote > 0)
            && (precoCamarote > 0) && (codigoFrente > 0)
            && (capacidadeFrente > 0) && (precoFrente > 0)
            && (codigoMeio > 0) && (capacidadeMeio > 0) 
            && (precoMeio >0) && (codigoFundo > 0) 
            && (capacidadeFundo > 0) && (precoFundo > 0))
    {
        //do Something};
    }
}
```

It´s an ugly code....
Even if I still use the IF part of the code, is there an alternative syntax that I could use to make this code more presentable?

Comment: Is it possible to consolidate those values into an object and perform validation when you construct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you ought to have objects here -- a `camarote` object, a `frente` object, a `meio` object, a `fundo` object -- each of which has three fields, which are guaranteed by the constructor to be nonnegative.

Comment: (If you were checking `>= 0`, as opposed to `> 0`, you could use bit-twiddling tricks like `(a | b | c | d | e | ...) >= 0`, which is equivalent to `a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && ...`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use the constructor approach as suggested by Louis, then try this

```
void abreTeatro(int... values) {
   for(int val: values) {
      if(val <=0) {
         // print error if needed
         return;
      }
    }
    // Code here assuming everything is +ve
    // you have an array in values, so you have to retrieve the values in the same order as in the calling method

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper method:

```
public static boolean allPositive(int... numbers)
{
  for(int number : numbers)
  {
    if(number < 0)
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

And then use e.g.

```
if (allPositive(codigoCamarote,capacidadeCamarote,precoCamarote,codigoFrente,capacidadeFrente,precoFrente,codigoMeio,capacidadeMeio,precoMeio,codigoFundo,capacidadeFundo,precoFundo)
{
  //do Something
};
```

Alternatively, to eliminate the braces use:

```
if(!allPositive(...))
  return;

// do something
```